# X11 not working on one of two identical boxes

Tags: 14.04, ssh, xorg

I have two installations of Ubuntu 14.04.  I keep them both up-to-date, and have configured them just about identically.

Using an XServer on a third box (MobaXterm 9.4 on Windows 7), I can readily access X11 apps on one host (a desktop), but NOT on the the other (a laptop).

I always get this error:

```
** (gedit:5785): WARNING **: Could not open X display
(gedit:5785): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: 192.168.1.53:0.0
```

I have compared the two boxes' `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` files: they are identical.
I have compared the two boxes' list of installed packages (with `dpkg --get-selections`): they seem to have all the same x11.* xorg.* and xserver.* packages.

What are other possible reasons the X11/SSH features are not acting the same?

What do I check next?

I'm willing to post my ssh_config file and list of installed packages, but I didn't want to bother if that is not helpful (given I'm claiming they are nearly identical.)

ONE MORE HINT:  when I start my SSH sessions with MobaXterm, connecting to the desktop host (where X11 is working), MobaXterm seems to sense the server is set up correctly, sets the DISPLAY value, and gives this message:

```
• SSH compression : ✔                                           
• SSH-browser     : ✔                                           
• X11-forwarding  : ✔  (remote display is forwarded through SSH)
• DISPLAY         : ✔  (automatically set on remote server)
```

But connecting to the laptop (where X11 is NOT working), MobaXterm gives this message:

```
• SSH compression : ✔                                       
• SSH-browser     : ✔                                       
• X11-forwarding  : ✘  (disabled or not supported by server)
• DISPLAY         : 192.168.1.53:0.0
```

Any idea why MobaXterm would detect on the laptop host "disabled or not supported by server"?  (Again, from all my snooping, I'd say these servers are configured identically for SSH and X11.)

Maybe I have to diddle some files like `.Xauthority`.  Or maybe I have different VNC servers or clients installed on the two boxes.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have compared `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` in both machines, but this is the configuration file for SSH clients, for making SSH connections *from* those machines.

You should compare `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` (notice the *d*) in both machines, this is the configuration file for SSH servers, for receiving SSH connections *to* those machines.

In `sshd_config`, make sure `X11Forwarding` is uncommented and set to `yes`.

Comment: Dang. So simple.  I didn't know the distinction.  Thanks!  (I know why I didn't suspect to look for "sshd_config": the ssd daemon *service* is called "ssh" when you use the command `sudo service ssh restart`.  So I figured its settings were in `ssh_config`.  Sigh.  That is what you get when you expect consistency...)

Comment: A very typical Unix pattern is that *daemons* have names that end in *d*. So the SSH service is handled by an `sshd` program, hence the config file name. A common pitfall in the case of SSH, because people tend to use and configure the SSH server as much as the SSH client.